# WebRTC Call from Browser to Android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am having issues on connecting WebRTC Call from Browser to Android Native App. Just to clarify that When we dial from Android to Web Browser, It works and call is connected.

Following is SDK Browser when dialing from Browser

> v=0
>
> o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-67.0.2 3998696948364254257 0 IN IP4
>   0.0.0.0
>
> s=-
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=fingerprint:sha-256
>   DB:52:AF:5F:F1:55:DC:C6:AF:AA:2D:4F:83:BC:78:58:EE:DA:81:E2:BA:81:34:C1:B9:14:5B:D8:B0:40:07:5D
>
> a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
>
> a=ice-options:trickle
>
> a=msid-semantic:WMS *
>
> m=audio 57545 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
>
> c=IN IP4 176.9.75.12
>
> a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 63270 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 51377 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 2 TCP 2105524478 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 110.38.9.108 63270 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 63270
>
> a=candidate:2 1 UDP 92217343 176.9.75.12 57545 typ relay raddr
>   176.9.75.12 rport 57545
>
> a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 110.38.9.108 51377 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 51377
>
> a=candidate:2 2 UDP 92217342 5.9.205.188 59742 typ relay raddr
>   5.9.205.188 rport 59742
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=end-of-candidates
>
> a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
>
> a=extmap:2/recvonly urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:csrc-audio-level
>
> a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
>
> a=fmtp:109 maxplaybackrate=48000;stereo=1;useinbandfec=1
>
> a=fmtp:101 0-15
>
> a=ice-pwd:ad76ac59889d2dbfc17c7197a5bf7fbc
>
> a=ice-ufrag:4a27971e
>
> a=mid:0
>
> a=msid:{403cebe3-98f3-804c-8711-63078fdeecd1}
>   {58497120-df50-c04f-929b-d0d3f2311ee6}
>
> a=rtcp:59742 IN IP4 5.9.205.188
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
>
> a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
>
> a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>
> a=setup:actpass
>
> a=ssrc:430883687 cname:{dc7d4aa2-5678-c745-ab1b-16660383829b}
>
> m=video 52189 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 121 126 97
>
> c=IN IP4 176.9.75.12
>
> a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 52775 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 62134 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 2 TCP 2105524478 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 110.38.9.108 52775 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 52775
>
> a=candidate:2 1 UDP 92217343 176.9.75.12 52189 typ relay raddr
>   176.9.75.12 rport 52189
>
> a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 110.38.9.108 62134 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 62134
>
> a=candidate:2 2 UDP 92217342 5.9.205.188 60881 typ relay raddr
>   5.9.205.188 rport 60881
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=end-of-candidates
>
> a=extmap:3 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
>
> a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
>
> a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
>
> a=fmtp:126
>   profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
>
> a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
>
> a=fmtp:120 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
>
> a=fmtp:121 max-fs=12288;max-fr=60
>
> a=ice-pwd:ad76ac59889d2dbfc17c7197a5bf7fbc
>
> a=ice-ufrag:4a27971e
>
> a=mid:1
>
> a=msid:{403cebe3-98f3-804c-8711-63078fdeecd1}
>   {ec535e56-859b-0040-af22-dfc9a46de640}
>
> a=rtcp:60881 IN IP4 5.9.205.188
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
>
> a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:97 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
>
> a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
>
> a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
>
> a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
>
> a=setup:actpass
>
> a=ssrc:2007361327 cname:{dc7d4aa2-5678-c745-ab1b-16660383829b}

Following is SDP from Android while accepting call

> v=0
>
> o=- 7552000228569576067 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
>
> s=-
>
> t=0 0
>
> a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
>
> a=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS
>
> m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 101
>
> c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>
> a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>
> a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 63270 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 51377 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 2 TCP 2105524478 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 110.38.9.108 63270 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 63270
>
> a=candidate:2 1 UDP 92217343 176.9.75.12 57545 typ relay raddr
>   176.9.75.12 rport 57545
>
> a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 110.38.9.108 51377 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 51377
>
> a=candidate:2 2 UDP 92217342 5.9.205.188 59742 typ relay raddr
>   5.9.205.188 rport 59742
>
> a=ice-ufrag:Pmla
>
> a=ice-pwd:CAEYOQZF7+JSa/YT4tDXWqFv
>
> a=ice-options:trickle renomination
>
> a=fingerprint:sha-256
>   58:DB:E8:47:30:8D:FD:04:3B:C0:6A:E1:68:6A:31:C2:C4:00:4A:51:74:6B:24:9C:13:E1:3F:BB:B0:AB:14:7B
>
> a=setup:active
>
> a=mid:0
>
> a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
>
> a=fmtp:109 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
>
> a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>
> a=ssrc:1539343785 cname:bTZH1y7Pwq/SmE4A
>
> a=ssrc:1539343785 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0
>
> a=ssrc:1539343785 mslabel:ARDAMS
>
> a=ssrc:1539343785 label:ARDAMSa0
>
> m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 126 120 121
>
> c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>
> a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
>
> a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.1.101 52775 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 1 TCP 2105524479 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 192.168.1.101 62134 typ host
>
> a=candidate:11 2 TCP 2105524478 192.168.1.101 9 typ host tcptype
>   active
>
> a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 110.38.9.108 52775 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 52775
>
> a=candidate:2 1 UDP 92217343 176.9.75.12 52189 typ relay raddr
>   176.9.75.12 rport 52189
>
> a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1686052862 110.38.9.108 62134 typ srflx raddr
>   192.168.1.101 rport 62134
>
> a=candidate:2 2 UDP 92217342 5.9.205.188 60881 typ relay raddr
>   5.9.205.188 rport 60881
>
> a=ice-ufrag:Pmla
>
> a=ice-pwd:CAEYOQZF7+JSa/YT4tDXWqFv
>
> a=ice-options:trickle renomination
>
> a=fingerprint:sha-256
>   58:DB:E8:47:30:8D:FD:04:3B:C0:6A:E1:68:6A:31:C2:C4:00:4A:51:74:6B:24:9C:13:E1:3F:BB:B0:AB:14:7B
>
> a=setup:active
>
> a=mid:1
>
> a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
>
> a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> a=rtcp-mux
>
> a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
>
> a=fmtp:126
>   level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
>
> a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
>
> a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
>
> a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
>
> a=ssrc:1992667211 cname:bTZH1y7Pwq/SmE4A
>
> a=ssrc:1992667211 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0
>
> a=ssrc:1992667211 mslabel:ARDAMS
>
> a=ssrc:1992667211 label:ARDAMSv0

Answer (score 1):

My gut reaction (from experience) is to tell you that making and receiving a call has different workflows.  Make sure that you're creating an Offer when making a call and an Answer when receiving the call.  Make sure you are setting the SDP's correctly as the local or remote.

Other than that...

Do you get any errors?

Does your peer connection get to state Connecting or Connected?

Do you get the onAddStream callback?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Same Android App is working with Android to Android and Android iOS and iOS to Android

Comment: It sounds like your problem is in your javascript code then.  Have you tried making a browser to browser call?